# Mapping columns in excel with text based entries?

Tags: excel, text-parsing, vba

First Spreadsheet [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY2Rx.jpg) ("carwale" in the formula is the second spreadsheet)

I have two spreadsheets, one column in first one and a second one in other needs to be mapped on the basis of the entries which are in text format and this mapping is needed to be done on the basis that the entries are exactly the same or approximately same. Few of the entries are mapped which were easy to find(i.e exactly the same using vlookup) and the rest are still unmapped. Can someone please help me with this ?

Second spreadsheet [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJQLZ.jpg)

I have added images of the two spreadsheets .. I hope it will help !!

And it's my first question here !! Any suggestions for improving the way of asking questions would be great ..

Comment: Please show what you've done so far to solve this.

Comment: just edited it, I hope it answers your question ...

Comment: You need to show some examples of data and expected output.  It is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: added images ... I hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `VLOOKUP` function is:

***VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])***

where `[range_lookup]` is an optional parameter which accepts TRUE or FALSE. `FALSE` is to find an exact match where as `TRUE` is for approximate match.

Your formula `=VLOOKUP(C2:C1666,Carwale!G:H,2,False)` gives you the result when exact match is found and gives error `#NA` when no match is found.

So in that case when no match is found you can use function for approximate matches `=VLOOKUP(C2:C1666,Carwale!G:H,2,TRUE)`

In case you want to club these two condition use following formula which will first look for exact match and if not found will give you approximate result:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C1666,Carwale!G:H,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(C2:C1666,Carwale!G:H,2,TRUE))
```

Comment: @DataEnthusiast_95 - Did this help?